# Is there an API for ordering flowers?

Tags: api

Does an API exist for ordering flowers? I’m thinking of something like FTD or 1800flowers?

I could always make a mechanize script to walk through the site, but I'm a little scared of how brittle a solution that would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just doing a quick google search I found:

https://www.floristone.com/api/

Looks to be exactly what you're looking for as far as I know. Good luck!